# Dagger 2 public field injection produces 'private field injection' error

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to set up a very basic field injection using `Dagger2` with the following structure:

```
class ToInject {}
```

```
class Injected {
    @Inject
    var toInject: ToInject? = null
}
```

```
@Module
object BaseModule {

    var toInject: ToInject? = null

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun toInjectProvider(): ToInject {
        if (toInject == null) {
            toInject = ToInject()
        }

        return toInject as ToInject

    }
}
```

The field I'm trying to inject is definately **PUBLIC** but the compiler returns the following error

> Dagger does not support injection into private fields

Can anyone please explain why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

BTW constructor injection works:

```
class Injected @Inject constructor(var toInject: ToInject){}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try explicitly annotating the setter method:

```
class Injected {
    @set:Inject
    var toInject: ToInject? = null
}
```

or

```
class Injected {
    var toInject: ToInject? = null
        @Inject set
}
```

You can also annotate your field as `@JvmField`:

```
class Injected {
    @JvmField
    @Inject
    var toInject: ToInject? = null
}
```

---

The problem is how Kotlin is translated to Java.

This Kotlin class:

```
class Injected {
    var toInject: ToInject? = null
}
```

actually becomes this Java class:

```java
public final class Injected {
    @Nullable
    private ToInject toInject;

    @Nullable
    public final ToInject getToInject() {
        return this.toInject;
    }

    public final void setToInject(@Nullable ToInject value) {
        this.toInject = value;
    }
}
```

So despite the fact you set your field public in Kotlin, under the hood it's just a private field with a public setter and getter.

Comment: This does resolve the compilation error but the field is still null at runtime :(

Comment: @SirCodesalot: How do you create an `Injected` instance? Fields won't be injected unless Dagger is responsible for the object creation or is told to perform the injection by invoking a members-injecting method. Basically you should just add a non-argument constructor for the `Injected` class annotated with `@Inject` to allow Dagger create its instances.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issue while injecting primitive Int value. Only adding `@JvmField` worked for me. Thanks @jsamol for pointing out.

```
@JvmField
@Inject
@Named(NAMED_APP_LOGO)
var appLogo: Int = 0
```